# Why doesn't my MinArray implementation recycle unused ids?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a basic MinArray, that is, an array wrapper that pushes deleted ids into a queue,
and reuses recycled ids before incrementing length;

However, my MinArray doesn't recycle the id's, it just keeps incrementing.

The complete code, with a test can be found at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkY2r/).

This code inserts a new value and returns the assigned id:

```
MinArray.prototype.insert = function(val){
    var id;
    var recycledId = this._recycledIds.shift();
    if(recycledId){
        id = recycledId;
    }else{
        id = this._nextId++;
    }
    this._vals[id] = val;
    this._executeCallbacks(this.oninsert, this._vals[id]);
    this.length++;
    return id;
};
```

and this code removes an item from the array:

```
MinArray.prototype.remove = function(id){
    if(this._vals[id]){
        this._executeCallbacks(this.onremove, this._vals[id]);
        delete this._vals[id];
        this._recycledIds.push(id);
        this.length--;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, do you know of any good existing implementations that I can freely use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `if(recycledId){`  to `if(recycledId !== undefined){`  because the way you wrote it zero is also false - while it should be true to work

edit:
same bug also in the `remove` function - if your _vals[id] contain zero (or false or empty string) it will not be removed.  Better change `if(this._vals[id]){` to `if(this._vals[id] !== undefined){`  and note to the developers that the MinArray cannot contain 'undefined' values as data.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is surprisingly simple:

```
MinArray.prototype.insert = function(val){
    var id;
    var recycledId = this._recycledIds.shift();
    if(typeof recycledId === 'number'){ // <<<<<
        id = recycledId;
    }else{
        id = this._nextId++;
    }
    this._vals[id] = val;
    this._executeCallbacks(this.oninsert, this._vals[id]);
    this.length++;
    return id;
};
```